# How do I draw two lines of text in GMS and keep one static?

Tags: game-maker, windows, scripting

I am making an intro sequence for my game, but I'm having some difficulty drawing two lines of text. The first line is "DEVELOPED BY:" referenced from a separate language file as "IntroSequence", "DevelopedBy". The next line (made by using `+ chr(13) + chr(10) +`) is my name which I want to be kept static. I would essentially like the user to be able to make different language files being able to change the string reference "DEVELOPED BY:", but not the developer name. Now, I can get the text to draw if I use "DEVELOPED BY:#Mr.Mendelli" in the language file, or keeping both strings static in the script by declaring `mytext = get_text("DEVELOPED BY:" + chr(13) + chr(10) +"Mr. Mendelli");`. But If I use the second method, the `DevelopedBy` string cannot be translated in the language resource any more.

When I use the below script, GMS says two arguments are declared, but three are provided:

```
mytext = get_text("IntroSequence", "DevelopedBy" + chr(13) + chr(10) +"Mr. Mendelli");
image_alpha = 0;
statetime = 0;
```

How do I use my alias as an unchangeable separate line?

Comment: `mytext = get_text("IntroSequence", "MadeBy") + chr(13) + chr(10) +"Mr. Mendelli";`? Or even just `mytext = get_text("IntroSequence", "MadeBy") + "#Mr. Mendelli");`

Comment: Of course! I forgot to close the first line, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you for your solution. If you provide it as an answer I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing brace at wrong place. Must be:

```
mytext = get_text("IntroSequence", "MadeBy") + chr(13) + chr(10) +"Mr. Mendelli";`
```

or even just

```
mytext = get_text("IntroSequence", "MadeBy") + "#Mr. Mendelli";
```